# Connect to MongoDB via mongoose

Tags: database, mongodb, react-native, mongoose

i am trying to build a simple connection to a mongodb.
If possilbe i would like to use mongoose for that. I am using React Native and Expo.
I have seen that in the documentation of MongoDB it says that i can`t use MongoDB directly with Expo. Thats the reason for mongoose.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const mongoURL = '***';

mongoose.connect(mongoURL);

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB Connection error"));
```

This is part of my App.ts

My tsconfig.json is this

```
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react",
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

So far when building the app on my android device i get the error
**_mongoose.default.connect is not a function**

Haven´t been able to resolve this with past questions yet.

I am also open to other cloud-based databases

Is this even the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a server to connect your client (app) to the database (mongo), all your secrets can be revealed in the source code of the app so its very unsafe.
check this article https://rahmanfadhil.com/express-rest-api/ for simple explanation

Comment: i am totally aware of the security being more or less non-existent here. This is jsut a "start to get to know how" project with 0 intentions of going to a live published build

- Still thank you for the information!